# Is there any value of zeta that is an integer?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, riemann-zeta

Is there any value which we can substitute for $s$ in $\zeta (s)$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n^{-s}\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Note that, $\lim_{s\to \infty}\zeta(s)=1 $.

Comment: I thought $\zeta (s)$ increases as $\lim_{n \to \infty }$ because $\zeta (2) \approx  1.6$ and $\zeta (4) \approx  10$. Interesting :D

Comment: @user2357 That's because it's not injective (aka it changes "direction").

Comment: @Ataraxia On the interval $(1,\infty)$ where the sum representation is convergent, $\zeta$ should be decreasing because each term in the sum is. And $\zeta(4)\approx 1.08$. See [specific values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values).

Comment: Oh, yes, i had a 9 instead of the 90 lol. Thank you!

Comment: Look at the graph of $\zeta$. It should be obvious that for every real number $r>1$ there is an $s$ such that $\zeta(s)=r$. This is hardly a fact peculiar to the zeta function; it applies anytime a function is continuous by intermediate value theorem as noted in the comments below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$\zeta(s)$ is a continuous function with $\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} \zeta(s) = 1$ and $\lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \zeta(s) = \infty$ (on the real line), so it takes every positive integer at some $s > 1$. Just the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: How do you know it's continuous?

Comment: Many ways.. it's analytic for one. More elementarily you can look at $\zeta(s + \delta) - \zeta(s)$. Given $\epsilon$ and $N$, if $\delta$ is small enough the difference of the first $N$ terms can be made less than ${\epsilon \over 2}$, and also the sum of the absolute values of the remaining terms will be less than ${\epsilon \over 2}$ if $N$ were chosen large enough

Comment: Is it not possible for $\zeta(s)$ to evaluate to an integers for $s<\infty $. Is it possible to prove that it doesn't?

Comment: @user2357 Do you know the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)?

Comment: Every positive integer, except $\zeta=1$, unless you allow $\zeta(+\infty)$.

Answer (score 3):

When we analytically continue $\zeta$ to values of $s$ where the series doesn't converge, we get the famous Riemann zeta function, for which $\zeta(-2)=0$. That might be the easiest integer value to write down!